# How to simply send a request parameter with jquery form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I am able to submit a form as `Post` type using the following in my javascript:

```
$("#receiptsForm").submit();
```

But I also want send across a parameter `myparam` as well with the request which I'll be retrieving in my spring controller using `httpServletRequest.getParameter("myparam")`:

```
var myparam = "abc";
$("#receiptsForm").submit();
```

What's the best I can do?

Comment: you can add a hidden field in form before submit the from using js

Comment: Question is not clear, you want to submit with ajax or simply submit with jquery.

Comment: Okay I'll use this for now, until I find if there is really some parameter sending thing in jquery.

Comment: @Zeeshan Jquery it is.

Comment: @user2918640 can you write your form code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
function form_submit()
{
      //var myparam = "abc";

     // add hidden field to your form name="myparam" and value="abc"
      $('#receiptsForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="myparam " value="abc" />');
      $("#receiptsForm").submit(); 
}
```

Comment: Do I get to retrieve this parameter using request.getParameter("myparam") in controller?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am able to retriev in controller like `httpServletRequest.getParameter("myparam")`

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
var input = $("<input>")
               .attr("type", "hidden")
               .attr("name", "mydata").val("bla");
$('#receiptsForm').append($(input));
$('#receiptsForm').submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `serializeArray`

```
var data = $('#receiptsForm').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'myparam', value: 'MyParamValue'});
```

You can send the `data` like:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
     data: data,
    ...
});
```

Comment: can you do this without using ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using jquery..there are a couple of ways this can be done..either you can make it a object and then pass it as data in an ajaxrequest

```
var myparam = "abc";

var data_to_be_sent = {"myparam":myparam};
```

then in the data field of the ajax request, you can

```
data : data_to_be_sent.
```

Or you simply have a hidden field in the form and then on submit you can give it a value of myparam

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that spring to mind

a) include a hidden form field called `myparam` in your form, and the use jquery to populate it with `abc` before submitting.

b) use Jquery's ajax to call a `ajax post`, and before doing this set the data parameter.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```